# Any danger in having spammy Twitter followers

Tags: malware, spam-prevention, twitter, phishing

I routinely receive notifications of obviously spammy Twitter users following me, e.g. accounts with names like @freemoneynow, etc.  Is there a danger in allowing them to follow me if I do not follow them back?  They could always send me a direct message with a phishing link, but aside from that, is this something I should be aware of?  It becomes a maintenance headache if I have to actively prune my list of followers (admittedly not huge, but all it takes is one bad apple).

Comment: This question will get closed. But in the meantime, the answer to this question is somewhere in the question, "why are they adding you in the first place?" I'm not sure either.

Answer (score 5):

They can't DM you if you don't follow back.

You can block them if you want to, or you can use one of the many [3rd party services](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=twitter+remove+spam+followers&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=21352e299d88a25) around to do so.

It doesn't really have any effect. It's basically just a number. You'll probably find a lot of them disappear naturally from time to time when Twitter purges spam accounts or they unfollow you because you're not following them back.

Comment: I've noticed that if you ignore them they tend to disappear after a while.

Answer (score 3):

They are usually just trying to get you to look at their links (money pyramids, xxx sites..) - basically to generate more traffic. So they probably don't pose too much threat, unless you publish all of your sensitive data online, but that is an issue for itself.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is have a "locked accout" and thus, I have to approve all of my followers...This cuts down **big-time** on spammy followers, and many don't even bother to request to follow me...